# Почему subscribeOn() не отправляет предыдущее значение из Behaviour subject?

Tags: java, android, события, rxjava

Изучаю нюансы работы методов `subscribeOn()` / `observeOn()` для `Subjects`. Не могу понять, почему в приведенном коде `subscribeOn()`  запрещает отправку события `str 0`?

```
    val observer: Observer<String> = object : Observer<String> {
    override fun onComplete() {
        println("Consumption onComplete [thread] - ${Thread.currentThread().name}\"")
    }

    override fun onNext(item: String) {
        println("Consumption onNext $item [thread] - ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
    }

    override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
        println("Consumption onError ${e.message} [thread] - ${Thread.currentThread().name}\"")
    }

    override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {
        println("Consumption onSubscribe [thread] - ${Thread.currentThread().name}\"")
    }
}

val subject = BehaviorSubject.create<String>()

subject.onNext("str 0 ")

subject
    .doOnNext { println("doOnNext $it [thread] - ${Thread.currentThread().name}\"") }
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe(observer)

subject.onNext("str 1")

Thread.sleep(4000)
```

Вывод будет такой:

```
Consumption onSubscribe [thread] - main"

doOnNext str 1 [thread] - RxComputationThreadPool-1"

Consumption onNext str 1 [thread] - RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
```

**Если закомментировать `subscribeOn()`, то событие `str 0` веже придет при подписке:**

```
Consumption onSubscribe [thread] - main"

doOnNext str 0  [thread] - main"

doOnNext str 1 [thread] - main"

Consumption onNext str 0  [thread] - RxCachedThreadScheduler-1

Consumption onNext str 1 [thread] - RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
```

Почему это происходит?

Answer (score 1):

Потому что из-за `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())` подписка на upstream планируется, собственно, на `Schedulers.computation()`. К тому времени как произойдёт подписка, строка `subject.onNext("str 1")` будет уже выполнена. Поэтому первым значением, которое увидит подписчик будет `"str 1"`

`ObservableSubscribeOn::subscribeActual`:

```
@Override
public void subscribeActual(final Observer<? super T> observer) {
    final SubscribeOnObserver<T> parent = new SubscribeOnObserver<T>(observer);
    observer.onSubscribe(parent);
    parent.setDisposable(scheduler.scheduleDirect(new SubscribeTask(parent)));
}
```

Тут мы видим, как планируется задача подписки `scheduler.scheduleDirect(new SubscribeTask(parent))`

В `SubscribeTask::run` происходит подписка на `source` (upstream)

```
final class SubscribeTask implements Runnable {
    private final SubscribeOnObserver<T> parent;
    SubscribeTask(SubscribeOnObserver<T> parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        source.subscribe(parent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Может строка subject.onNext("str 0") будет уже выполнена, а не subject.onNext("str 1")?

Comment: @Novikov Обе, если угодно. Смысл в том, что подписка откладывается на другой поток, поэтому строка `subject.onNext("str 1")` выполнится раньше подписки и перезапишет предыдущее значение `"str 0"`, А когда подписка всё же случится, первым значением мы увидим `"str 1"`